# Login with Splinter is not setting document.cookie

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, splinter

I want to login to a https web page using Splinter. However, it seems that cookies are not set when I login. Here is my code:

```
from splinter import Browser
import time

username = 'blabla'
password = 'blabla'

with Browser('chrome') as browser:
    browser.visit("https://the.login.page")

    browser.fill('p_username', username)
    browser.fill('p_password', password)
    browser.find_by_css('.button').first.click()

    time.sleep(2)

    browser.visit('https://other.page.after.login')
```

I get to the other page, but I am not logged in.

- `browser.cookies.all()` is not empty, and it correctly contains my **SESSIONID** value. But...
- `document.cookie` (in the browser console) is empty.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

I also tried using `selenium` and I get the same result:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

username = 'blabla'
password = 'blabla'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://the.login.page')
time.sleep(2)

username_field = browser.find_element_by_name("p_username")
password_field = browser.find_element_by_name("p_password")
username_field.send_keys(username)
password_field.send_keys(password)

login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
login_attempt.submit()
time.sleep(2)
browser.get('https://other.page.after.login')
```

Comment: Just to debut it: what if you increase the sleep to, say 20, seconds - does that make any difference?

Comment: @alecxe Nothing changes unfortunately.

Comment: are both pages on the same domain? remember, the cookies are usually per domain

Comment: @KurtBourbaki Can you include in your post the Set-Cookie response headers when you login using a normal browser?